# Javascript function to conditionally move video playhead runs twice

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm writing some javascript to move the playhead of a video. The video consists of a series of sections which play through, then stop. A row of buttons sends the playhead to specific section.

The video is an animated sequence that is seamless between sections. To preserve that seamless quality, when section buttons are pressed, sections need to play through to their end before jumping to a new chapter.

An example:

• Playhead is paused at 7 seconds, and the end of the section is at 10 seconds.

• The user hits button 3 to go to the 30 second mark.

• The current section must finish by playing to 10 seconds.

• Once the current section is finished, *then* the playhead can jump to the 30 second mark.

Here’s the snag I’m hitting: when called with an onClick(), each button function is running twice. On the first run, the if statement is always going to else.

```
var vid=document.getElementById("neufVideo");

Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
    get: function(){
        return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
    }
});

function playPause() {
    console.log("playPause");
    if(vid.playing){
        console.log("playPause pause");
        vid.pause();
    } else {
        console.log("playPause play");
        vid.play();
    }
}

var button2 = function(){
    console.log("button2");
    window.vid=document.getElementById("neufVideo");
    vid.addEventListener("timeupdate",button2);
    vid.play();
    if(this.currentTime >= 5){
        // remove the event listener
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",button2);
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
        console.log("button2 condition 'currentTime >= 5' met");
        //return;
    } else {
        console.log("button2 else");
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",button2);
        //return;
    }
    //return;
};

var button1 = function(){
    console.log("button1");
};
```

You can see a test page with the video at https://micadesign.ca/neuf/

I'm very new to coding so if I'm going about this all wrong I'd be happy to be pointed in the right direction.

(By the way, there will be no more than five playhead scenarios, so I’m not thinking along the lines of a more complex solution that would scale.)

Thanks!

Comment: `button2` is called when you click on the button and also when the `timeupdate` event is triggered on the video.

Comment: When you invoke the function with `onclick="button2()"` `this.currentTime` won't work. No context is passed, so it's equivalent to `window.currentTime`.

Comment: Okay, I switched away from 'this' to 'vid', and now it's working as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of adding the event listener and then immediately removing it in both `if` and `else` branches?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent the button function from constantly running, which is my current problem. Right now `button2()` keeps running until it hits the if condition. I think I don't really know how event listeners work on the whole.